# How to create video from still images in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, video-conversion

I am new to MATLAB. I am trying to encrypt video file in MATLAB. I encrypted the individual frame of video. I am using MATLAB 7.10.0 (R2010a) , that's why I used "mmreader" fumction. But now I am not getting how to reassemble all the encrypted frames into a new video. here is my code,

```
vid = mmreader('videoSampl.avi');
numFrame = vid.NumberOfframes;

for i = 1:2:3
   frame = read(vid, i);
   gray = rgb2gray(frame);
   n = numel(gray);
   plaintext = reshape(gray, n, 1);
   cipherImg = cipher (plaintext, w, s_box, poly_mat, 1);
   re_plaintext = inv_cipher (cipherImg, plaintext, w, inv_s_box, inv_poly_mat, 1);
   img = reshape(cipherImg, 128, 128);
   imwrite(img,['videoaes/encrypted/image' int2str(i), '.jpg']);
   imgP = reshape(re_plaintext, 128, 128);
   imwrite(imgP,['videoaes/decrypted/Dimage' int2str(i), '.jpg']);
   im(i)=image(frames);
end
```

I have two folders encrypted and decrypted, I want to convert these folders into avi video again.

Comment: see `help VideoWriter`. And why do you choose a lossy format for encrypted data?

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code to convert video from ur encrypted images

```
ImagesFolder=uigetdir;
jpegFiles = dir(strcat(ImagesFolder,'\*.png'));
S = [jpegFiles(:).datenum]; 
[S,S] = sort(S);
jpegFilesS =jpegFiles(S);
VideoFile=strcat(ImagesFolder,'\MyVideo');writerObj=VideoWriter(VideoFile);
fps= 10; writerObj.FrameRate = fps;
open(writerObj);
fort=1:length(jpegFilesS)Frame=imread(strcat(ImagesFolder,'\',jpegFilesS(t).name))writeVideo(writerObj,im2frame(Frame))endclose(writerObj;
```

Comment: Send me the whole code which u used for encrypting individual frames